# Explaining margins and dealing with tiles

Tags: html, css

I have few problems that I cannot fix, I will be grateful if somebody will explain me how it works. Firstly, i have a container with id "kafle", I positioned it as I wanted, and now i want to place a few tiles into it. I want do something like this: [image] I want to tile 1 be 50% width of container with id "kafle", and tile to be another 50% width. I set margin and padding of tile 1 and 2 to 0, but despite this, there is something what makes that tile 2 is going under tile 1, and i don't know why. The other problem is that i don't know how i can place tile 3, 4, 5 and 6 under tile 1, but in one line with tile 2. When im setting display: inline-block to all of the tiles, tile 3, 4, 5 and 6 are going under height of tile 2. How can I deal with it? I will be grateful for explaining it.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}


#kafle{
    position:relative;
    height: 80%;
    width: 60%;
    top:10%;
    left:20%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

#onas{
    background-color: coral;
    height:33%;
    width:49%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#aktualnosci{
    background-color: firebrick;
    height:90%;
    width:49%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#galeria{
    background-color: forestgreen; 
    height:10%;
    width:15%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#wspierajanas{
    background-color: khaki; 
    height:10%;
    width:15%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#kontakt{
    background-color: fuchsia; 
    height:10%;
    width:15%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#minigra{
    background-color: fuchsia; 
    height:10%;
    width:15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  
    <div id="kafle">
        <div id="onas">1</div>
        <div id="aktualnosci">2</div>
       <div id="galeria">3</div>
        <div id="wspierajanas">4</div>
        <div id="kontakt">5</div>
        <div id="minigra">6</div>
    </div>
  
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: css grid would be so perfect for this, but *full* support just isn't really there for IE.  The reason why you're seeing space like that is because of the `inline-block`.  It respects whitespace, so you can think of it like words in a text block.  Newlines, tabs, and spaces will be rendered as a space.  After adding HTML comments and updating the percentages to be 50%, you can see that the spacing disappears: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/7s8yLq8x/.  I would instead recommend flexbox.  Does your project allow for it?

Comment: Flexbox would require nested flex-containers. You can't acheive that layout with a single container.

Comment: @Paulie_D Granted, but unless css grid can be used (which theoretically a hacked together definition could be achieved cross-browser with a lot of pain and misery), there's no way this will be achieved without javascript or a wrapper to help flex out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, because I hate myself, I decided to build this layout in [CSS Grid (CSS Tricks article)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), which has [spotty compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) and [no consistency](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/).

Regardless, your layout is achievable using this fairly recent addition to CSS.  The trick is of course landing on a syntax that will work consistently for most browsers.  Below is one that seems to work well across the major ones.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}


#kafle{
  position:relative;
  height: 80%;
  width: 60%;
  top:10%;
  left:20%;
  background-color: aquamarine;

  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
      -ms-flex-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

#onas{
  background-color: coral;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}

#aktualnosci{
  background-color: firebrick;
  grid-column: 4 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  -ms-grid-column: 4;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 6;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
}

#galeria{
  background-color: forestgreen; 
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}

#wspierajanas{
  background-color: khaki; 
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}

#kontakt{
  background-color: fuchsia; 
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}

#minigra{
  background-color: fuchsia; 
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="kafle">
  <div id="onas">1</div>
  <div id="aktualnosci">2</div>
  <div id="galeria">3</div>
  <div id="wspierajanas">4</div>
  <div id="kontakt">5</div>
  <div id="minigra">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a [Weave](https://liveweave.com/MxPvya) for your question.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tiles</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="tile1">
      <h1>Tile 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tile2">
      <h1>Tile 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tile3">
      <h1>Tile 3</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="bottomLeftTiles">
      <div class="tile4">
        <h1>Tile 4</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="tile5">
        <h1>Tile 5</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="tile6">
        <h1>Tile 6</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

h1 {text-align: center;}

.tile1 {
  width: 50%; height: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}

.tile2 {
  width: 50%; height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0;
}

.tile3 {
  width: 49.6%; height: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 33%;
}

.bottomLeftTiles {
  width: 49.6%; height: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 66%;
}
.tile4 {
  width: 33%; height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}
.tile5 {
  width: 33%; height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%; top: 0;
}
.tile6 {
  width: 33%; height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66%; top: 0;
}
```

You may have to resize a few of the elements but I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the position of the objects with respect to one another is troubling you.

1. Set #id{display:inline:block;}
   Now the div behaves like block.
2. Use #id{position:relative widthtomove px lengthtomove px;}
   Now set the two relative parameters accordingly for each of your box(or division) and keep varying till they align themselves perfectly.

You may consider referring to detailed use of position:relative but the above should do the work!